# Combine Query results into one comma separated entry

Tags: mysql, sql

I am fairly new to SQL and im not sure if this is possible, but as the title suggests I want to combine the results of a query into one "entity" that I can then later insert into another table.
Here is an example:

```
SELECT COLUMN1
FROM TABLE1
```

Let's say the output is this:

```
COLUMN1
-------
data1
data2
data3
```

What I want to do is to take the result of this query and turn it into this:

```
data1,data2,data3
```

Which I can then insert into another table as one row like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2(RESULT)
VALUES ('data1,data2,data3')
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Storing *multiple values* in a single cell in a relational database is a big **NO-NO** - it violates even the *first normal form* of relational database design, and it ends up being a headache and a messy proposition in the long run. Avoid doing this - use *proper relational design* to handle 1:n relationships!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to get a list of all your column values:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN1 SEPARATOR ',') FROM TABLE1
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3cf4ecc/5/0

To directly `INSERT` the result of this `SELECT` you can use the following:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN1 SEPARATOR ',') FROM TABLE1
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/466869/1/1

---

You can also use a [`VIEW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) to keep your tables normalized:

```
CREATE VIEW V_TABLE1 AS SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN1 SEPARATOR ',') FROM TABLE1;
```

The advantage of a `VIEW` is that it is always generated from the current values of your table.

---

... **but be careful:** As [marc_s already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46693684/combine-query-results-into-one-comma-separated-entry/46693782#comment80335069_46693684) in the comments, it is not recommended to store multiple values as a list in a single column. You should always design normalized databases.

Comment: Just because you can does not mean you should.  Take heed of the advice to NOT do this.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an aggregate function such as string_agg in postgresql , simply as  SELECT string_agg(COLUMN1, ',') FROM TABLE1;

Certainly you can combine it with INSERT, i.e INSERT ...SELECT.